# Does a hidden UIWebview layout or paint a webpage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webkit

Does the iOS operating system prevent the DOM layout and painting of a webpage loaded in the webview if the given webview is hidden in the background (of the app)? Say, the webview is part of a view controller that is not made visible yet but I've asked the webview to load a URL.

Answer (score 0):

The system doesn't draw nor layout any view that is not part of the view hierarchy. You can easily verify it by subclassing UIWebView and overriding drawRect and layoutSubviews. That said, in almost all cases, you shouldn't have to care.

Comment: Ok. But I was specifically asking about the DOM paint/layout of a webpage that is loaded in the hidden webview. Because that process is CPU intensive, I believe. I edited the question for greater clarity.